# Changing dependency of WebSharper.JQueryUI to load jquery-ui.js locally

Tags: jquery-ui, f#, websharper

I'm writing on a WebSharper sitelet that uses the JQueryUI extension. The HTML generated by the WebSharper sitelet looks like this:

```xml
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js" ...></script>
```

I'm frequently without internet while developing, so I'd really like to serve `jquery-ui.js` off the development server instead. That is, I'd much rather have this:

```xml
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" ...></script>
```

The [docs](http://www.websharper.com/extensions/jqueryui) say this should be possible by setting an appropriate `appSetting` in `Web.config`, but no value I set for the keys listed in the docs seem to have any effect on the output.

I'm using (NuGet versions) WebSharper 3.0.54.140 and WebSharper.JQueryUI 3.0.45.241.

How do I force WebSharper to output a link to a resource local to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there is an error in the documentation. The key to use is the fully qualified name of the resource type, so for WebSharper.JQueryUI it should be:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="WebSharper.JQueryUI.Dependencies+JQueryUIJs" value="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js" />
  <add key="WebSharper.JQueryUI.Dependencies+JQueryUICss" value="/Content/jquery-ui.css" />
</appSettings>
```

Edit: just fixed the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, what's with the plus in "...Dependencies+JQueryUIJs"?

Comment: It's the IL notation for nested types. Here `Dependencies` is an F# module, so from the point of view of the runtime `JQueryUIJs` and `JQueryUICss` are nested types. If you type `typeof<WebSharper.JQueryUI.Dependencies.JQueryUIJs>.FullName;;` in F# interactive, you will get the +.