# Redefine jQuery dependency search path

Tags: f#, resources, offline, websharper

I have found that a typical Websharper "hello world" application does not work offline due to the inaccessibility of jQuery resource "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js". The question is: can I override this search path to the local folder of my web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` and place it in `Scripts`. Then add this to your `Web.config` as child of the root tag `configuration`:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="WebSharper.JQuery.Resources.JQuery" value="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
</appSettings>
```

If you want to do similarly with jquery-ui, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076131/changing-dependency-of-websharper-jqueryui-to-load-jquery-ui-js-locally) helps.